# How to fix "command not found" and missing env entries in ssh terminals

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, docker

### Desired behavior

When connected via ssh, "pip" (and other tools) should be available, just like they are in a "normal" terminal.

Also all the environment variables that are present in normal terminal sessions should be available in a ssh session (or in a shell opened via ssh).

### Current behavior

Trying to execute "pip" gives a "command not found" error when connected through ssh, but the command works properly when executed in a normal terminal.

### Setup

The ssh daemon is running in a docker container based on the image `nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:20.08-py3`.
It is exposed as port 30022.

Opening `/bin/bash` as an interactive terminal into the container works as expected with all the tools available and environment variables set. The user inside the container is the default (root) user - same when connecting through ssh.

The ssh connection is done using a rsa keypair with the pubkey added in the container's `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

### Things tried

Connecting with `ssh -p 30022 root@localhost`, or `ssh -p 30022 root@localhost -t "bash -l"` didn't give a shell with the desired behavior.

Executing `su -` in a ssh session didn't help.

Doing `source /root/.bashrc` in a ssh session didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630571/docker-env-variables-not-set-while-log-via-shell

For anyone having the same problem:

This problem was docker specific. The environment variables are set in the Dockerfile nvidia's image is built from. To restore the environment variables in a ssh session, I added `RUN env > /etc/environment` to my Dockerfile that's using the nvidia image as a base.

The file is read and used to populate the environment on ssh sessions as well, which also solves the missing `$PATH` entries responsible for the "command not found" error when calling `pip` or other tools.